# Statistics on a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, statistics

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
tmp= []
for y in range(0, 1000, 10):
    for x in range(0, 1000, 2):
        tmp.append({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

Now i would like to get for example the statistics.mode of key 'x'

```
mode= statistics.mode(tmp)
```

This will not work, as `statistics.mode` expects a list of int, string, float, etc...
but not dicts.

is there any way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you may construct an array within a dict instead of dict. like `tmp =  {'x':[], 'y':[]}`

Comment: Indeed, actualy i was thinking to just store it in a structured list: tmp[(10,5),(21,89)] but i need this structure to feed a chart in chart.js. i think it might be best to use dataframes from pandas and convert this to the desired chart format

Answer (score 1):

*Now i would like to get for example the statistics.mode of key 'x'*

Use comprehension to convert `list`s of `dict` into iterable of values, example:

```
import statistics
t = [{'x':1,'y':1},{'x':3,'y':2},{'x':3,'y':3}]
mode_x = statistics.mode(i['x'] for i in t)
print(mode_x)
```

output

```
3
```

Note that `statistics.mode` like many functions from python built-in modules is happy to accept iterable (i.e. it does not have to be `list`). This approach rather than building list and then passing it should take less time, but that might become visible only for big enough input data. Beware that `statistics.mode` might raise `statistics.StatisticsError` if there is more than 1 most common value (for example `statistics.mode([1,2,3])`).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a list comprehension -

```
import statistics
tmp= []
for y in range(0, 1000, 10):
    for x in range(0, 1000, 2):
        tmp.append({'x': x, 'y': y})
    
mode = statistics.mode(d['x'] for d in tmp)
```

Note: this will return `0` for the toy example created, because all `x` values show up only once, so the mode is ambiguous, and the first element is as good as any, which is what `mode` returns...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed the example is ambiguous since the elements only exist once. The use of the List comprehension is a clean solution.